# When using mocks, there is some cases I cannot cover in my tests

Tags: go, testing, mocking

I'm testing my `Compute()` method.

The `Compute()` method is making a HTTP Call `GetMeters()` to an external service. I'm mocking it.

Mock is returning a slice of objects which contains a field `staticPercent`.

If I sum all those `staticPercent`, I must have exactly 100%.

Off course, my mock is sending me this correct data so that the sum is 100%, but then I cannot test the case where sum of `staticPercent` is not 100, as the mock will always send me the same values ?

Any idea how to achieve that ?

EDIT:

Here is the mock

```
func (m *MockMetadataClient) GetMeters() ([]MeterInfo, error) {
    var meterInfos []MeterInfo

    c1 := MeterInfo{
        ID:             "36",
        Static_percent: 10,
    }
    c2 := MeterInfo{
        ID:             "19",
        Static_percent: 50,
    }
    c3 := MeterInfo{
        ID:             "20",
        Static_percent: 20,
    }
    c4 := MeterInfo{
        ID:             "21",
        Static_percent: 20,
    }
    
    meterInfos = append(meterInfos, c1, c2, c3, c4)

    return meterInfos, nil
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to mock this external service?

Comment: Yep, I added the mock.

Comment: I do something like this when I mock clients (to try and trigger the erroneous cases but to maintain the interface) https://play.golang.org/p/NVUJ3PDcnVB another option is just have a dedicated mock to test this type of error?

Comment: good catch @Christian, it worked well ! You can put it as answer, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two options:

1. Define a new mock (almost like a ~partial~ mock) and have the methods return erroneous results. (I wouldn't opt for this, if the interface is large you might leave unimplemented methods and it would leave the mock quite fragile)
2. Have a property that let's you toggle between different outputs.

I do something like this (the second option) when wanting to test these types of edge cases ([runnable playground here](https://play.golang.org/p/NVUJ3PDcnVB))

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type MyService interface {
    GetMeters() ([]MeterInfo, error)
}

type MeterInfo struct {
    ID            string
    StaticPercent int
}

type MockMetadataClient struct {
    ShouldGiveIncorrectStaticPercent bool
}

func (m MockMetadataClient) GetMeters() ([]MeterInfo, error) {
    c1 := MeterInfo{
        ID:            "36",
        StaticPercent: 10,
    }
    c2 := MeterInfo{
        ID:            "19",
        StaticPercent: 50,
    }
    c3 := MeterInfo{
        ID:            "20",
        StaticPercent: 20,
    }
    c4 := MeterInfo{
        ID:            "21",
        StaticPercent: 20,
    }

    infos := []MeterInfo{c1, c2, c3, c4}

    if m.ShouldGiveIncorrectStaticPercent {
        infos = append(infos, MeterInfo{
            ID:            "00",
            StaticPercent: 50,
        })
    }

    return infos, nil
}

func main() {
    myMockClient := MockMetadataClient{ShouldGiveIncorrectStaticPercent: false}

    infos, _ := myMockClient.GetMeters()
    total := sumPercents(infos)
    if total != 100 {
        fmt.Printf("error, wanted 100%% got %d%%\n", total)
    }

    // now with the error
    myMockClient.ShouldGiveIncorrectStaticPercent = true
    infos, _ = myMockClient.GetMeters()
    total = sumPercents(infos)
    if total != 100 {
        fmt.Printf("error, wanted 100%% got %d%%\n", total)
    }

}

func sumPercents(infos []MeterInfo) int {
    totalPercent := 0
    for _, i := range infos {
        totalPercent += i.StaticPercent
    }
    return totalPercent
}
```